# Botão de deletar não funciona

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Criei um botão de deletar que fica na linha de cada registro que estou exibindo em uma tabela, mas quando clico nele e exibo a tela de exclusão, percebo que sempre é selecionado o último registro da tabela, independente do item que clico. Abaixo segue meu código, agradeço sugestões de solução!

tela de exclusão:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="php/excluir.php">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Excluir </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Você tem certeza que deseja excluir?
        <?php
          $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM itens WHERE descricao = 'descricao'");
          while($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $exibir['id'];
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '"/>';
          } 
        ?>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Sim</button>
        </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

excluir.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
if (!$conexao) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
}

$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from itens WHERE id = '$id'");
$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from tabela WHERE id = '$id'");

if ($result) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../home.php'); </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>";     
}

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Comment: É 1 modal para 1 registro ? Ou 1 modal para vários registros ?

Comment: O modal é para o registro selecionado, só 1

Answer (score 1):

Aqui ele pega todos os IDs do loop que você faz ali no modal e exclui:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="php/excluir.php">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Excluir </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Você tem certeza que deseja excluir?
        <?php
          $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM itens WHERE descricao = 'descricao'");
          while($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $exibir['id'];
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $id . '"/>';
          } 
        ?>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Sim</button>
        </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$ids = $_POST['id'];

$conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
if (!$conexao) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
}

if(!empty($ids)){

  foreach($ids as $id){

    $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from itens WHERE id = '$id'");
    $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from tabela WHERE id = '$id'");

  }

}

if ($result) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../home.php'); </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>";     
}

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Comment: Não entendi, isso funciona para deletar só 1?

Comment: não. Ele pode excluir multiplos, bastar estar selecionado.

Comment: Eu sei, mas gostaria de saber se para excluir 1 só, funciona deste jeito também

Comment: sim, somente selecionar o qual deseja excluir

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa transformar os checkboxs em um array, adicionando [] colchetes no atributo name.

É necessário adicionar colchetes[] no nome do checkbox caso contrário apenas o último valor é enviado.

Quando você coloca um "name" com colchetes ele é enviado na forma de vetor ou array para o receptor.

A solução dada pelo amigo **Alisson Acioli** é nesse sentido.

> Considerações

No atributo name, no final de seu nome, colocamos colchetes, indicando que poderá ser enviado mais de um valor para o mesmo campo. Podemos utilizar essa notação para outros campos também, como por exemplo, campos de texto

```
<input type="text" name="nome[] value="Fulano" />
<input type="text" name="nome[] value="Ciclano" />
```

E se submetermos o formulário com esses elementos, temos o seguinte resultado

```
Array
(
    [nome] => Array
         (
            [0] => Fulano
            [1] => Ciclano
         )
)
```

Podemos ter esse comportamento para todos os campos existentes no formulário, text, radio, checkbox etc...

> Tratando vários campos checkbox de mesmo nome com PHP

```
<?php
 $ids= $_POST['id'];

   if (!empty($ids)) {                
       $qtd = count($ids);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $qtd; $i++) {
         $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from itens WHERE id = '".$ids[$i]."'");
         $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE from tabela WHERE id = '".$ids[$i]."'");
       }
   }

?>
```